# Assigning Variable to Dropdown ID

Tags: php

I'm having difficulty assigning a PHP variable to a HTML form data.

I have assigned other text fields as variable but when I mimic this in a  function it's just not playing ball...

My HTML code (only basic to start off) is:

```
<select id="userbrand">
<option> Option1</option>
<option> Option2</option>
<option> Option3</option>
```

**and the corresponding PHP code is:**

```
$camp_name = $_POST['campName'];
$broad_date = $_POST['broadDate'];
$userdomain = $_POST['userbrand'];
```

campName and broadDate contain the POST data from some text fields before the dropdown.

When submitting the form, I receive the following error:

**Notice: Undefined index: userbrand in C:\wamp64\www\action_page.php on line 19**

Is this an issue with my PHP code or my HTML?

Many Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
<select id="userbrand">
```

To this

```
<select id="userbrand" name="userbrand">
```

PHP gets the input value based on the input name, not the id.